# Integrate Application With VC++ application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse application that creates some file and then calls upon a second external application developed in VC++ with that file as input. Is there any way by which i can integrate the VC++ application into my eclipse application without much coding (I do not want to migrate the VC++ application to Eclipse Application) may be adding a view or editor in my eclipse application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experiences with that but it may could be done using the OLE support in Eclipse. See [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-ActivexSupportInSwt/index.html) for a description how to embed OLE objects in SWT.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I  understood how to integrate the application, but the problem now is that it requires a program ID. i tried to find the program Id of the application from Windows registry but it seems that the application does not have a program ID. IS there any alternate approach by which i can integrate or any way by which i can assign a program ID to the application

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/).

> JavaTM Native Interface (JNI) is a standard programming interface for writing Java native methods and embedding the JavaTM virtual machine* into native applications. The primary goal is binary compatibility of native method libraries across all Java virtual machine implementations on a given platform.